# How to get the name of tables or attributes in MySQL Workbench 8.0

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have installed MySQL Workbench 8.0 and I'm making querys from MySQL 8.0. I would like to know if I can activate some option to "predict" the name of the tables or attributes of a table when I write a query.

I've got this property by default, I don't do anything to get it, when I have been working with older version of MySQL Workbench and making querys from MySQL 5.5.

How can I make that MySQL Workbench predict the names of tables or attributes?

**EDIT I:**

The config of my Workbench is:

[image]

Here, If I push Ctrl+Space don't give me any result:

[image]

Comment: Did you see this : https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=91859?

Comment: Thank you @DanB!!! I have checked my configuration and I think is correctly. This configuration let me autocomplete sql commands but no the name of tables because when I press Ctrl+Space doesn't give me any result :( I have updated my original post with my config.

Comment: OK @DanB, finally I have seen that is a bug!!! Thanks for your appreciated help!!

Comment: I just put in answer, so you can close this thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to wait for next version, there is a bug in current version :  bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=91859?